# escaping characters after query string rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, urlencode

After rewriting query string in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &q=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/search)$ $1?q=%1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Characters like Ė,Į,Š,Ų,Š,Ų are converting to %C4%96,%C4%AE,%C5%A0,%C5%B2,%C5%A0,%C5%B2. Is any way to disable these characters converting? My search doesn't work when search term becomes  %C4%96ien instead of šien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `NE` flag to prevent a double encode from happening in the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &q=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/search)$ $1?q=%1 [R=301,NC,L,NE]
```